# What can I do to correct my code on how to display salaries based off of education levels using switch statements?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, break

In this problem, we are asked to:

Write a switch statement to set the average salary of a person based on their type of completed education. Print the following message to the console.

In 2015, a person with __________ earned an average of __________/year.

I just started coding so please be gentle. :)

This is my current code:

```
var education = "a Doctoral degree";
var salary = "";
var output = "In 2015, a person with " + education + " earned an average of $" + salary;

switch (education) {
case "no high school diploma":
    output += "25,636/year";
    break;
  case "a high school degree":
    output += "35,256/year";
    break;
  case "an Associate's degree":
    output += "41,496/year";
    break;
  case "a Bachelor's degree":
    output += "59,124/year";
    break;
  case "a Master's degree":
    output += "69,732/year";
    break;
  case "a Professional degree":
    output += "89,960/year";
    break;
  case "a Doctoral degree":
    output += "84,396/year";
}

console.log(output + ".");
```

If I were to display a person's salary with a Bachelor's degree, it would correctly display it as:

In 2015, a person with a Bachelor's degree earned an average of $59,124/year.

My current code (while testing out all options) prints the correct messages but I receive the following error:

What Went Wrong
- output is not defined

Comment: My code isn't normally this poorly formatted and I'm new to stackoverflow so I apologize!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use some IDE which can format your code automatically and highlight syntax error, please check Visual Studio Code for example :)

Below example of your code:

```
var education = "a Doctoral degree";
var salary = "";

switch (education) {
    case "no high school diploma":
        salary = "25,636/year";
        break;
    case "a high school degree":
        salary = "35,256/year";
        break;
    case "an Associate's degree":
        salary = "41,496/year";
        break;
    case "a Bachelor's degree":
        salary = "59,124/year";
        break;
    case "a Master's degree":
        salary = "69,732/year";
        break;
    case "a Professional degree":
        salary = "89,960/year";
        break;
    case "a Doctoral degree":
        salary = "84,396/year";
        break;
}

var output = "In 2015, a person with " + education + " earned an average of $" + salary;

console.log(output + ".");
```

Here you can see execution result:
[image: Execution result]

Please specify when you have this message:

> What Went Wrong - output is not defined

Happy coding :) Maybe try some youtube tutorial with js setup and hello world programs.

Comment: Thank you, I use Atom already but it reformatted everything when posting the question. Thanks anyways!